# Don't send notification if author comments his own post plugin help?

Tags: plugins, author, notifications, comments

is there any way to set an IF statement, that If the author of the post commented or replied  on his own post that the wp notification is not sent to him, only if a different user comments he would recieve the notification?. I am using the Notify on comment plugin.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Notify on comment
Plugin URI: http://www.artbits.it
Description: Send a notification on comment to the author of the post
Version: 1.03
Author: Fabio Trezzi 
Author URI: http://www.artbits.it
*/

function notifyOnComment_send($commentID){
global $wpdb;
// Get the email of the post's author
$comment = get_comment($commentID);
$post = get_post($comment->comment_post_ID);
$user = get_userdata($post->post_author);
$to = $user->user_email;
// Set the send from
$admin_email = get_option('admin_email');
$headers= "From:noreply@bonetoz.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To:$noreply@bonetoz.com\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

$comment_author_domain = @gethostbyaddr($comment->comment_author_IP);
$comments_waiting = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT count(comment_ID) FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_approved = '0'");

$moderationOpt = get_option('notifyOnComments_moderationRequired');

if($moderationOpt == 'true'){
    // Only send the notification if the comments requires to be moderated
    $approved = $comment->comment_approved;
    if($approved != 0) return;  // No need to send the mail the comment is already approved
}   

$template = get_option('notifyOnComments_emailTemplate'); 
// If not setted load the default from file
if($template || $template == "") $template = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/defaultTemplate.php');

// Replace all the constant with the rights values
$template = str_replace("{postID}", $post->ID, $template);
$template = str_replace("{postTitle}", $post->post_title, $template);
$template = str_replace("{author}", $comment->comment_author, $template);
$template = str_replace("{authorIp}", $comment->comment_author_IP, $template);
$template = str_replace("{authorDomain}", $comment_author_domain, $template);
$template = str_replace("{authorEmail}", $comment->comment_author_email, $template);
$template = str_replace("{authorUrl}", $comment->comment_author_url, $template);
$template = str_replace("{commentContent}", $comment->comment_content, $template);
$template = str_replace("{commentLink}", get_permalink($comment->comment_post_ID), $template);
$template = str_replace("{commentID}", $commentID, $template);
$template = str_replace("{commentsWaiting}", $comments_waiting, $template);
$template = str_replace("{siteUrl}", get_option('siteurl'), $template);

$subject = sprintf( __('[%1$s] Please moderate: "%2$s"'), get_option('blogname'), $post->post_title );

@wp_mail($to, $subject, $template, $headers);

return true;

}

function notifyOnComment_menu() {
$path = dirname(__FILE__);
$pathElements = explode('/', $path);
add_options_page('NotifyOnComments options', 'NotifyOnComments', 'manage_options',   $pathElements[count($pathElements) - 1] . '/options.php');
}

add_action('comment_post', 'notifyOnComment_send');
add_action('admin_menu', 'notifyOnComment_menu');

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but from quick look something like this should work:

```
$comment = get_comment($commentID);
$post = get_post($comment->comment_post_ID);
$user = get_userdata($post->post_author);

if( $comment->user_id == $post->post_author )
    return;
```