# Disable WP notifications for commenting on own posts

Tags: email, notifications

How/where can I disable WP email notifications for commenting on own posts?

I want to do this globally for all users on the site, not only per-user through WP admin.

Are there any hooks which I can use to cancel these emails?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this link


[http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33185/dont-send-notification-if-author-comments-his-own-post-plugin-help][1]


  [1]: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33185/dont-send-notification-if-author-comments-his-own-post-plugin-help

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't help - it's about a hack of a contributed plugin.

Answer (score 2):

The function that sends emails to the post author is called `wp_notify_postauthor()` and is located in `/wp-includes/pluggable.php`. This means that the function is "pluggable" and can be overridden by another function with the same name. We can make a simple plugin to do this.

This is the code we'll be adding to the function to check if the author is posting on his own comment.

```
if ( $comment->comment_author_email == $author->user_email ) {
     return false;
}
```

And here is the completed plugin for Wordpress version 3.6. This needs to be saved in a PHP file called `custom-author-notification.php` and saved in a folder called `custom-author-notification` in your plugins directory `/wp-content/plugins/`.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Author Notification
Description: Stops authors from receiving emails when they comment on their own posts. Replaces the default wp_notify_postauthor() function in Wordpress v3.6.
Version: 1.0
*/

if ( ! function_exists('wp_notify_postauthor') ) :
function wp_notify_postauthor( $comment_id, $comment_type = '' ) {

$comment = get_comment( $comment_id );
$post    = get_post( $comment->comment_post_ID );
$author  = get_userdata( $post->post_author );

// The comment was left by the author
if ( $comment->user_id == $post->post_author )
    return false;

// The comment was also left by the author.
// Checks comment author email against post author email.
if ( $comment->comment_author_email == $author->user_email ) {
        return false;
}

// The author moderated a comment on his own post
if ( $post->post_author == get_current_user_id() )
    return false;

// The post author is no longer a member of the blog
if ( ! user_can( $post->post_author, 'read_post', $post->ID ) )
    return false;

// If there's no email to send the comment to
if ( '' == $author->user_email )
    return false;

$comment_author_domain = @gethostbyaddr($comment->comment_author_IP);

// The blogname option is escaped with esc_html on the way into the database in sanitize_option
// we want to reverse this for the plain text arena of emails.
$blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);

if ( empty( $comment_type ) ) $comment_type = 'comment';

if ('comment' == $comment_type) {
    $notify_message  = sprintf( __( 'New comment on your post "%s"' ), $post->post_title ) . "\r\n";
    /* translators: 1: comment author, 2: author IP, 3: author domain */
    $notify_message .= sprintf( __('Author : %1$s (IP: %2$s , %3$s)'), $comment->comment_author, $comment->comment_author_IP, $comment_author_domain ) . "\r\n";
    $notify_message .= sprintf( __('E-mail : %s'), $comment->comment_author_email ) . "\r\n";
    $notify_message .= sprintf( __('URL    : %s'), $comment->comment_author_url ) . "\r\n";
    $notify_message .= sprintf( __('Whois  : http://whois.arin.net/rest/ip/%s'), $comment->comment_author_IP ) . "\r\n";
    $notify_message .= __('Comment: ') . "\r\n" . $comment->comment_content . "\r\n\r\n";
    $notify_message .= __('You can see all comments on this post here: ') . "\r\n";
    /* translators: 1: blog name, 2: post title */
    $subject = sprintf( __('[%1$s] Comment: "%2$s"'), $blogname, $post->post_title );
} elseif ('trackback' == $comment_type) {
    $notify_message  = sprintf( __( 'New trackback on your post "%s"' ), $post->post_title ) . "\r\n";
    /* translators: 1: website name, 2: author IP, 3: author domain */
    $notify_message .= sprintf( __('Website: %1$s (IP: %2$s , %3$s)'), $comment->comment_author, $comment->comment_author_IP, $comment_author_domain ) . "\r\n";
    $notify_message .= sprintf( __('URL    : %s'), $comment->comment_author_url ) . "\r\n";
    $notify_message .= __('Excerpt: ') . "\r\n" . $comment->comment_content . "\r\n\r\n";
    $notify_message .= __('You can see all trackbacks on this post here: ') . "\r\n";
    /* translators: 1: blog name, 2: post title */
    $subject = sprintf( __('[%1$s] Trackback: "%2$s"'), $blogname, $post->post_title );
} elseif ('pingback' == $comment_type) {
    $notify_message  = sprintf( __( 'New pingback on your post "%s"' ), $post->post_title ) . "\r\n";
    /* translators: 1: comment author, 2: author IP, 3: author domain */
    $notify_message .= sprintf( __('Website: %1$s (IP: %2$s , %3$s)'), $comment->comment_author, $comment->comment_author_IP, $comment_author_domain ) . "\r\n";
    $notify_message .= sprintf( __('URL    : %s'), $comment->comment_author_url ) . "\r\n";
    $notify_message .= __('Excerpt: ') . "\r\n" . sprintf('[...] %s [...]', $comment->comment_content ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $notify_message .= __('You can see all pingbacks on this post here: ') . "\r\n";
    /* translators: 1: blog name, 2: post title */
    $subject = sprintf( __('[%1$s] Pingback: "%2$s"'), $blogname, $post->post_title );
}
$notify_message .= get_permalink($comment->comment_post_ID) . "#comments\r\n\r\n";
$notify_message .= sprintf( __('Permalink: %s'), get_permalink( $comment->comment_post_ID ) . '#comment-' . $comment_id ) . "\r\n";

if ( user_can( $post->post_author, 'edit_comment', $comment_id ) ) {
    if ( EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS )
        $notify_message .= sprintf( __('Trash it: %s'), admin_url("comment.php?action=trash&c=$comment_id") ) . "\r\n";
    else
        $notify_message .= sprintf( __('Delete it: %s'), admin_url("comment.php?action=delete&c=$comment_id") ) . "\r\n";
    $notify_message .= sprintf( __('Spam it: %s'), admin_url("comment.php?action=spam&c=$comment_id") ) . "\r\n";
}

$wp_email = 'wordpress@' . preg_replace('#^www\.#', '', strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']));

if ( '' == $comment->comment_author ) {
    $from = "From: \"$blogname\" <$wp_email>";
    if ( '' != $comment->comment_author_email )
        $reply_to = "Reply-To: $comment->comment_author_email";
} else {
    $from = "From: \"$comment->comment_author\" <$wp_email>";
    if ( '' != $comment->comment_author_email )
        $reply_to = "Reply-To: \"$comment->comment_author_email\" <$comment->comment_author_email>";
}

$message_headers = "$from\n"
    . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"" . get_option('blog_charset') . "\"\n";

if ( isset($reply_to) )
    $message_headers .= $reply_to . "\n";

$notify_message = apply_filters('comment_notification_text', $notify_message, $comment_id);
$subject = apply_filters('comment_notification_subject', $subject, $comment_id);
$message_headers = apply_filters('comment_notification_headers', $message_headers, $comment_id);

@wp_mail( $author->user_email, $subject, $notify_message, $message_headers );

return true;
}
endif;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer - will check it and post back.